# definition of 'but until'

Tags: grammar, phrases

What does *but until* in a sentence mean? I came across the phrase in a sentence that sounded almost exactly as this:

> He was a great person **but until** he started caring for other people's feelings.

I have found another example of sentence, tweeted by Rupert Murdoch. His tweet was:

> Maybe most Muslims are peaceful, **but until** they recognize and destroy their growing jihadist cancer they must be held responsible.

A compact explanation to this tweet would be real handy.

Comment: The end of this sentence seems to be missing - can you provide the rest?

Comment: "but until" is not an independent unit in the sentence (sorry if the language is imprecise). It is the words "but" and "until" next to each other, and each plays a separate role.

Comment: I have added a more understandable example. You guys may read it and help me with it afterwards. Thanks

Comment: Both of your examples have problems.  The first is missing the rest of the sentence, and the second, at the very least, is missing "are".

Comment: Perhaps the first sentence has a word missing. It seems like it should be "He was a great person, but ***not*** until he started caring for other people's feelings." Otherwise it needs something else, for example: "He was a great person, but until he started caring for other people's feelings, ***his greatness would be overshadowed by his meanness.***"

Answer (score 1):

There is no phrase "but until". There are two words, *but* and *until*, which can be looked up in a dictionary.

Your second sentence could be rephrased as "Maybe most Moslems are peaceful.  However, until..."; the main verb is *must be held*.

The first sentence is ungrammatical. If you have remembered it correctly, the writer mistakenly inserted "but" or (more probably) omitted "not"; you should remember that many writers are in a hurry on the Internet, and typos, infelicities and even grammatical errors do occur (even, occasionally, on EL&U).

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is badly structured.

> Maybe most Moslems peaceful, but until they recognize and destroy their growing jihadist cancer they must be held responsible."

Paraphrase:

- It is possible that most Moslems are peaceful.
- Most Moslems [refuse to] recognize and destroy their growing jihadist cancer.
- [Therefore] most Moslems must be held responsible [for...*something*].
- When most Moslems recognize and destroy their growing jihadist cancer, then they don't have to be held responsible [for...*something*]

This doesn't make a lot of sense, obviously.

Comment: The sentence is entirely grammatical (once *are* is inserted) and makes perfect sense in lingusitic terms. You may disagree with the sentiment, but this is the wrong place to say so.

Comment: First, I'm not sure where you mean to insert "are." You should put it in a separate answer.

Second, I am not judging the sentiment, only its expression. When I said "this doesn't make a lot of sense," I meant it's literally non-sense, an accumulation of disconnected phrases.